# Automate simple Image editing

Tags: php, asp.net, image-processing, automation, image-manipulation

I'm working on an E-commerce website which deals in clothing and fabrics. Now what the client wants is that he click an image of a model once, and the same images is reused for different shirts. the only difference in each shirt is the print and texture.

The only way I know of achieving this is by manually editing it in photoshop. However I'd like to know if there is a way of automating this process.

I understand this might be a broad question,all I need is the name of any scripting language, or trick to get this done.

PS: Im well versed with html,css,javascript,jquery and php. However Im open to any other language that might do the trick.

Comment: For me, the question is not clear enough. And what would be roughly the process in photoshop?

Comment: Ok, If I were to do it manually, I've create a new layer above the model's image and then paste the new texture there. Next I'd wrap  and transform the texture layer so it sits exactly over the model's shirt as if he were wearing a new shirt. Now the wrapping and transforming is going to be the same every time I add a new texture. It's just the texture that's going to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what you would do in photoshop and it's not too complicated I would try to rebuild the process with [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) functions. I'm sure you'll find several tutorials...

Comment: Were you able to implement the required task?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm working my way towards it. Quite certain I'll accomplish what I seek.